# copy() is not working with Aviary photoeditor

Tags: php, image, copy

I am using **Avairy Editor** to edit photos. After Editing I want to copy that image to my folder but it is not copying.

This is my code using **copy** function

```
copy("http://featherfiles.aviary.com/2013-06-29/c-4n02w430qUbilqgQgRJw/23df66d714074321bb256a6e9ab4bf27.jpg","/home/content/04/8643604/html/iguanapaint/wp-content/uploads/2013/06/23df66d714074321bb256a6e9ab4bf27.jpg")
```

I also tried with **file_get_contents**

```
file_put_contents("/home/content/04/8643604/html/iguanapaint/wp-content/uploads/2013/06/23df66d714074321bb256a6e9ab4bf27.jpg",file_get_contents("http://featherfiles.aviary.com/2013-06-29/c-4n02w430qUbilqgQgRJw/23df66d714074321bb256a6e9ab4bf27.jpg"));
```

directory permissions are fine becuause when I copy the file without editing it on Aviary , it is easily copying.

Please help.  Thanks!!!

Comment: Too bad you haven't `error_reporting` enabled to tell us a bit more than it "is not working".

Comment: @mario I did not get what you mean ?

Comment: make sure that `allow_url_fopen` is set to `On` in php.ini that's usually what's blocking copying files from remote locations

Comment: @n1te on my localserver php.ini file there is no code for **allow_url_fopen**  and I have to do it on server and I dont have its php.ini file then how will I do it. Thanks

Comment: @user2307273 when you run `phpinfo()` on you localserver does it say that `allow_url_fopen` is `On` or `Off` ?

Comment: @n1te right!!! I checked it and it is off but now my problem is I dont have php.ini file of server how to do it then. Thanks

Comment: @user2307273 this should be set to `On` on the server you want to copy files to, not from. Since it's your localserver why whouln't you have access to php.ini?

Comment: I am not on localserver, I am doing on server. I just checked that on localserver also on server it is off and I dont have access of php.ini so how to set it on

Comment: @user2307273 if you don't have access to php.ini you have to ask your host to enable it

Comment: @n1te can we not set with php

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this in `.htaccess`

```
php_value allow_url_fopen On
```

but keep in mind that not all hosts allow this. If it doesn't work you have to contact your host and ask them to enable it for you.

Comment: Where to write in .htaccess

Comment: @user2307273 in the first line